# Tracking errors from prepared SQL statements

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, prepared-statement

I use extended events to store database errors, like this:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [ErrorCapture] 
ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.error_reported
(
    ACTION
    (
        sqlserver.client_hostname,
        sqlserver.database_id,
        sqlserver.sql_text,
        sqlserver.username
    )
    WHERE 
    (
        [severity] >= (11)
    )
) 
ADD TARGET package0.asynchronous_file_target
(
    SET filename='J:\ServerXmlOutput\ErrorCapture.xel'
)
WITH 
(
    MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,
    EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,
    MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=10 SECONDS,
    MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,
    MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,
    TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,
    STARTUP_STATE=ON
);
```

This helps me to easily trace which application is causing them.
I have something similar to track slow queries and other special cases.
However, I noticed from the SQL Server Profiles that a PHP/Laravel application is not sending some statements directly, but using RPC:Completed: they look like prepared statements, receiving the argument at run time.
How do I expand my ErrorCapture to include errors caused by statements executed via RPC:Completed?

Comment: Do you have cases where an RPC erred with severity >= 11 but was not captured by this trace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have does return errors from prepared statements. The below PowerShell executes a prepared statement against SQL Server that will intentionally fail. This appears in Profiler with RPC:Completed as you've described:

```
$SqlConn = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection]::New("Server=localhost;Database=master;Trusted_connection=true;")

$SqlConn.Open()

$SqlCmd = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand]::New($null, $SqlConn)

$SqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT @Val/0"

$idParam = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter]::New("@Val", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int, 0);
$idParam.Value = 1;
$SqlCmd.Parameters.Add($idParam);

$SqlCmd.Prepare()
$SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

$SqlConn.Close()
```

When I run this with Profiler and your Extended Events session running, I can see the error reported in both tools:

Extended Events:

[image: Extended Events]

Profiler:

[image: Profiler]

One issue may be that the messages are below severity 11, and so your EE session is excluding them. If you run a Profiler trace using the TSQL_Replay template and include "User Error Messages" under **Errors and Warnings** do your errors from prepared statements appear then?

If so, check the **error** column in Profiler and run the below against SQL Server replacing 8134 with the error number from Profiler:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.messages WHERE message_id = 8134
```

Check the **severity** column in that to identify the severity of the error returned by your prepared statements.